# Reoccurring htaccess command

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to continue this indefinatly in length without writing it out everytime.
Is there a way to achieve this?

```
RewriteRule   ^(\w+)/?$   index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule   ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$   index.php?page=$1&$1=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule   ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$   index.php?page=$1&$1=$2&$2=$3 [QSA,L]
```

So all the way through $1=$2 then $2=$3 so page=blog&blog=article&article=date&date=2012

My PHP then takes this and runs analysis on this. So could be as as $1 -> $11 Long URL I know means that I can still enable adding.

```
AAA.com/blog/article/date/2012/?colour=blue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as such. To get an replacement `$5` placeholder, you do need a match group.

One could of course optionalize it group-wise:

```
RewriteRule  ^(\w+)(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\w+))?/?$   index.php?page=$1&$1=$2&$2=$3&$3=$4&$4=$5&$5=$6  [QSA,L]
```

But then you had a few `&=&=&=` trailing for absent entries. Usually it should result in an empty `$_GET[""]`, but PHP even ignores that. So, might be an option. I don't feel it's a more readable or concise RewriteRule though.

Comment: I'll leave it as it is for now. I understand it like that atm. Thanks anyway.